# How to read some specific files from a collection of files as one RDD

Tags: file, scala, apache-spark

i have a collection of files in a directory and i want to read some specific files form these files as one RDD , for example:

```
2000.txt
2001.txt
2002.txt
2003.txt
2004.txt
2005.txt
2006.txt
2007.txt
2008.txt
2009.txt
2010.txt
2011.txt
2012.txt
```

and i want to read every Specific range from these files, for example:

```
range = 4
from = 2004

then read files : 2004.txt , 2005.txt , 2006.txt , 2007.txt
as one RDD (data)
```

how can i do this in spark an scala?

Comment: First generate a sequence of file names, then call sc.parallelize on it and map or flatMap with a method that reads the file content? This of course assumes that the files are visible from all spark slaves.

Comment: @AHAD Where are these files stored? Local file system, HDFS, something else? What is the maximum size of the file?

Comment: these files are on local file system, and i want to run code on a cluster  of nodes .

Comment: There is also some support for path "gloms" (wild card expressions), e.g., `sparkContext.textFile("/path/to/200[89]*")` graps the 2008 and 2009 data.

Comment: @AHAD if the files are stored locally, you will have to copy them either to HDFS or to a nfs directory that is mapped from all spark nodes. Of course this won't be an issue if you are just playing around with a local instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because Spark's textFile exposes Hadoop's [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html), You can specify [varargs](http://daily-scala.blogspot.fr/2009/11/varargs.html) of directories and wildcards. Hence this should work (untested):

```
def datedRange(fromYear: Int, years: Int) = 
  sc.textFile(Seq.tabulate(years)(x => fromYear + x).map(y => s"/path/to/dir/$y"): _*)
```